# Subfields of field of cyclotomic 5th root of 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

What are all the subfields of the cyclotomic 5th root of 1.

My attempt:The galois  group over $\Bbb{Q}$ is $(\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z})^*=\{1,a^1,a^2,a^3\}$.The only possible non trivial subgroup is the subgroup generated by $a^2$.So the only possible non trivial subfield is the fixed field of this subgroup.

Comment: *Hint*: $2\cos(2\pi/5)$ satisfies a quadratic.

Comment: Do you know what $a$ does to the fifth root of unity $\zeta_5=e^{2\pi i/5}$? Once you figure that out you can show that $\zeta_5+\zeta_5^{-1}$ is stable under $a^2$. You can write it either using cosine or $\sqrt5$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think it sends the fifth root to its square

Comment: Yes. That is one correct alternative. So where will $a^2$ send $\zeta_5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Galois group shows that the only non-trivial subextension is quadratic, and algebraic number theory shows that the quadratic subfield of $\Bbb Q\left(\zeta_p\right)$ is $\Bbb Q\left(\sqrt{p^\ast}\right)$ where $p^* = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}2} p$ for any odd prime $p$, so in this case you get $\Bbb Q\left(\sqrt5\right)$.

It is left as an exercise to verify that indeed $\sqrt5 \in \Bbb Q\left(\zeta_5\right)$.

Comment: Is this is the fixed field of {1,$a^2$} ?

Comment: It is so, by Galois theory, which tells you that it is unique.

Comment: My favorite way to render $\sqrt5\in\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_5]$ is to use the quadratic Gauss sum to render $\pm\sqrt5=\zeta_5-\zeta_5^2-\zeta_5^3+\zeta_5^4$, the sign depending on the choice of root for $\zeta_5$.